# jQuery datetimepicker set end date when start is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How I can change the end date when the user selects the start time? I want to disable the days before the start time. It's homework, but I am new to jquery.

Thanks. Here is the code i managed to work, but i don't know what to change.

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          $('#end').val(moment().add(+1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
          });
          $("#checkAllEdit").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
          });

          $("#start, #end").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
          $("#start, #end").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
          });
        });
    </script>
```

THE WORKING VERSION:

```
          $('body').on('focus', ".dpicker", function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
          });

          $(function () {
            $("#start").datepicker({
              minDate: 1,
              changeMonth: true,
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
              onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
                if (selectedDate != '') {
                  $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                  var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);
                  var minDate2 = new Date(selectedDate);
                  minDate2.setDate(minDate2.getDate() + 1);

                  $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate2);
                  $("#end").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
                }
              }
            });
            $("#end").datepicker({
              minDate: 1,
              changeMonth: true,
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
              onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#star").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
              }
            });


          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to add **minDate: 0**  to set min date today

```
$("#start, #end").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: 0 /* This will be today */
});
```

If you want to add minDate to some other day you can just use 
**new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)** for example

```
$("#start, #end").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

EDIT to answer comment:

If you want to set end date, then you can use **setDate**

```
$("#start, #end").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    setDate: new Date(2016,10,03)
});
```

And it seems like you want end date to be 1 day after start date, then take start date value

```
var startDate = $('#start').datepicker('getDate') + 1; /* Get start date and add one day */
$('#end').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    setDate: startDate
});
```

For further reading: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: and how to jump to the end time dialog when the start time is selected?

Comment: Edited answer, sorry for long delay, went to sleep yesterday.

Comment: Hi! I edited my code as you sad, its a step in the right direction, but it has some bug?! https://postimg.org/image/u2bnbpe87/

Comment: nevermind, i managed to work out. Thanks for the help, i will accept your answer!

Comment: Good to hear that you found solution. :)